# How to extract parameters from URL?

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, split, scrapy

```
url = 'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/'
url2 = 'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/94/soups-stews-and-chili/'
new = url.split("/")[-4:]
new2 = url2.split("/")[-2:]
print(new)
print(new2)

Output : ['world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese', ''] 
         ['soups-stews-and-chili', '']
```

- The output I need is ['world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese'] & ['soups-stews-and-chili'].
- The URLs have different parameters I am not able to get around all the URL and extract only the main parameters after the numbers
- And also the '/' at end of the URL is necessary because in Scrapy when I use a URL w/o '/' it throws a 301 error but as you can see from the output there is an extra '' because of the backslash which I am not able to omit.
- what can I do to get the parameter for all sorts of URLs ?

some other examples of the URLs are :

'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/416/seafood/fish/salmon/'

'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/205/meat-and-poultry/pork/'

- how can we write the rule to follow such pagination for such URLs 'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/?page=2'

  Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'recipes/?page=\d+',)), follow=True)

I am new to scrapy and regex and hence i would really appreciate you help on this problem

Comment: *what can I do to get the parameter for all sorts of URLs ?* The thing is, these are not actually parameters though. Parameters are also called `query strings`. Read up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I correctly understood your question, but I think the following code gets you what you need.

**EDIT**
Updated code after comment interaction

```py
urls = [
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/416/seafood/fish/salmon/',
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/205/meat-and-poultry/pork/',
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/',
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/94/soups-stews-and-chili/',
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/qqqq/94/soups-stews-and-chili/x/y/z/q'
]

for url in urls:
    for index, part in enumerate(url.split('/')):
        if part.isnumeric():
            start = index+1
            break
    print(url.split('/')[start:-1])
```

**output**

```py
['seafood', 'fish', 'salmon']
['meat-and-poultry', 'pork']
['world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese']
['soups-stews-and-chili']
['soups-stews-and-chili', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

**old answer**

```py
urls = [
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/416/seafood/fish/salmon/',
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/205/meat-and-poultry/pork/',
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/',
    'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/94/soups-stews-and-chili/'
]

for url in urls:
    print(url.split("/")[5:-1])
```

**output**

```py
['seafood', 'fish', 'salmon']
['meat-and-poultry', 'pork']
['world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese']
['soups-stews-and-chili']
```

Comment: what about the URL `'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/qqqq/94/soups-stews-and-chili/x/y/z/q'` - the code does not work in this case.

Comment: that is true, but that was not provided as a sample URL. But that is easily fixed. See updated code

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `re` module + `str.split`:

```py
import re

urls = [
    "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/",
    "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/94/soups-stews-and-chili/",
    "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/416/seafood/fish/salmon/",
    "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/205/meat-and-poultry/pork/",
]

r = re.compile(r"(?:\d+/)(.*)/")

for url in urls:
    print(r.search(url).group(1).split("/"))
```

Prints:

```py
['world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese']
['soups-stews-and-chili']
['seafood', 'fish', 'salmon']
['meat-and-poultry', 'pork']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. The idea is to find the 'int' path element and fetch all path elements from its right side.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict, List

urls = ['https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/416/seafood/fish/salmon/',
        'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/205/meat-and-poultry/pork/']


def is_int(param: str) -> bool:
    try:
        int(param)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


data: Dict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(list)
for url in urls:
    elements = url.split('/')
    elements.reverse()
    loop = True
    while loop:
        for element in elements:
            if len(element.strip()) < 1:
                continue
            if not is_int(element):
                data[url].append(element)
            else:
                loop = False
                break
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/416/seafood/fish/salmon/': ['salmon', 'fish', 'seafood'], 'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/205/meat-and-poultry/pork/': ['pork', 'meat-and-poultry']})
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a url try to avoid (or a least delay) `regex` and look first to `urllib` or similar and/or `split()`.

**Just one url with full details:**

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urlparse(urls[4])

ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.allrecipes.com', path='/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/', params='', query='page=2', fragment='')
```

**Looping the list for `path` only and `split()`:**

```
# a list of urls
urls = ['https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/',
'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/94/soups-stews-and-chili/',
'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/416/seafood/fish/salmon/',
'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/205/meat-and-poultry/pork/',
'https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/?page=2']


for url in urls:
# https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/

    l = urlparse(url).path.split('/')
    # ['', 'recipes', '695', 'world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese', '']
    
    print(l[3:])
    # ['world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese', '']
    
    print('/'.join(l[3:]),'\n')
    # world-cuisine/asian/chinese/
```

**Full output of the above:**

```
['world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese', '']
world-cuisine/asian/chinese/ 

['soups-stews-and-chili', '']
soups-stews-and-chili/ 

['seafood', 'fish', 'salmon', '']
seafood/fish/salmon/ 

['meat-and-poultry', 'pork', '']
meat-and-poultry/pork/ 

['world-cuisine', 'asian', 'chinese', '']
world-cuisine/asian/chinese/
```

**Another example (not just the `path` this time):**

```
for parts in urls:
    print(list(urlparse(parts)), '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
['https', 'www.allrecipes.com', '/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/', '', '', ''] 

['https', 'www.allrecipes.com', '/recipes/94/soups-stews-and-chili/', '', '', ''] 

['https', 'www.allrecipes.com', '/recipes/416/seafood/fish/salmon/', '', '', ''] 

['https', 'www.allrecipes.com', '/recipes/205/meat-and-poultry/pork/', '', '', ''] 

['https', 'www.allrecipes.com', '/recipes/695/world-cuisine/asian/chinese/', '', 'page=2', '']
```